# Drawing shapes javascript

Tags: javascript, libraries, drawing2d

I have a web project that I have to create a virtual screen for example screen for mobile pc, in this screen I want to partition it into zones to subsequently assign displays on these areas, are they javascript libraries that facilitate drawing and recover the dimensions of these areas.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

D3 is the best option for doing so, https://d3js.org/

You can learn more about D3 in https://benclinkinbeard.com/d3in5days/ (easy email starter course) since D3 can be used in really complex ways to display data and figures